# cassandra java binding a collection of maps to a prepared statement

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver

I am using datastax' Cassandra Java driver. My Cassandra supports CQL 2 only.

I have a prepared INSERT statement that needs to accept a list of maps.

This is my schema:

```
CREATE TYPE test.snap_guid (
    l bigint,
    h bigint
);

CREATE TABLE test.t (
    id   bigint,
    snap list<frozen<snap_guid>>,
    PRIMARY KEY ((id))
)
```

This is the prepared statement:

```
PreparedStatement mysttmt = <client>.prepare("INSERT INTO test.t (id, snap) VALUES (?, ?)");
```

I know that in order to bind collections to the prepared statement I need to create a collection, and bind it. I cannot put the collection brackets in the prepared query. For instance (for list of text):

```
ArrayList<String> snaps = new ArrayList<>();
snaps.add("AEF34GF665");
// INSERT INTO test.t (id, snap) VALUES (?, ?)
BoundStatement bs = mysttmt.bind(12, snaps);
```

**My question is**: how do I bind a list of maps? How can I create a query like the next one?

```
INSERT INTO test.t (id, snap) VALUES (12, [{l:10,h:50}])

// I know it is impossible to create the following prepared statement:
INSERT INTO test.t (id, snap) VALUES (?, [{l:?,h:?}])

// The list of maps has to be a single bound variable... how???
INSERT INTO test.t (id, snap) VALUES (?, ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create tables:

   ```
   CREATE TYPE my_type (
   user_id text,
   name text,
   age bigint
   );

   CREATE TABLE my_table_with_set_of_udt (
   my_key text PRIMARY KEY,
   my_types set<frozen <my_type>>
   );

   CREATE INDEX ON my_table_with_set_of_udt(my_types);
   ```
2. Create mapping classes and beans:

   ```
   @UDT(keyspace = "my_ks", name = "my_type")
   public class MyType {
   @Field(name = "user_id")
   private String userId;

   @Field(name = "name")
   private String name;

   @Field(name = "age")
   private int age;

   // getters, setters & constructors
   // equals & hashCode are required for a set
   }

   @Table(keyspace = "my_ks", name = "my_table_with_set_of_udt")
   public class MyTableWithSetOfUDT {

   @PartitionKey
   @Column(name = "my_key")
   private String myKey;

   @Column(name = "my_types")
   @FrozenValue // because of --> set<frozen <my_type>>
   private Set<MyType> myTypes;

   // getters, setters & constructors
   // equals & hashCode are required for a set
   }

   @Bean
   public Mapper<MyTableWithSetOfUDT> myTableWithSetOfUDTMapper() {
   return new MappingManager(cassandraClient.getSession()).mapper(MyTableWithSetOfUDT.class);
   }

   @Bean
   public UDTMapper<MyType> myTypeMapper() {
   return new MappingManager(cassandraClient.getSession()).udtMapper(MyType.class);
   }
   ```
3. Create the prepared statements, for example:

   ```
   addUpdateStatement = cassandraClient.getSession().prepare("UPDATE my_table_with_set_of_udt SET my_types = my_types + ? WHERE my_key=?;");
   deleteUpdateStatement = cassandraClient.getSession().prepare("UPDATE my_table_with_set_of_udt SET my_types = my_types - ? WHERE my_key=?;");
   ```
4. Bind the parameters:

   ```
   MyType myType = MyType(userId, name, age);
   UDTValue value = myTypeMapper.toUDT(myType);
   cassandraClient.getSession().execute(addUpdateStatement.bind(Sets.newHashSet(value), myKey));
   ```

   or

   ```
   cassandraClient.getSession().execute(deleteUpdateStatement.bind(Sets.newHashSet(value), myKey));
   ```
5. Insert a record into the table with a value for `my_key` (You can do this directly in cql).
6. Run the code, now we can add/delete elements to the set by updating the table with our UDT.

Answer (score -1):

I have the solution.

It seems that the question was wrong. I needed to add a list of UDT (user defined tap), not list of hashes. For that you need to use UserType, and UDTValue:

```
UserType myUDT = <client>.getSession().getCluster().
    getMetadata().getKeyspace("test").getUserType("snap_guid");
UDTValue mySnap = myUDT.newValue();
mySnap.setLong("h", 50);
mySnap.setLong("l", 10);

ArrayList<UDTValue> snaps = new ArrayList<>();
snaps.add(mySnap);
// INSERT INTO test.t (id, snap) VALUES (?, ?)
BoundStatement bs = mysttmt.bind(12, snaps);
```